# How do I get these weird Material Emancipation Grills?

Tags: portal-2

I was playing a community-made *Portal 2* and i came across weird looking Material Emancipation Grills. There were a couple of them, a purple one and an orange one, and they both did something unique. For instance, I remember the orange one wasn't able to be passed through by anything, but you could shoot portals through it.

Bellow is an image from the internet i found of what i am talking about as I can't get a picture of them, whenever I try to the game crashes.

[image: Weird Material Emancipation Grills]

I was wondering how to get this "Mod", or just any way to get these items.

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking about Where to find this mod? Or are you asking about what this mod does?

Comment: @Ben i think the user, when they say *"this "Mod""* they were talking about the different Material Emancipation Grills thinking they are modded as opposed to unused in-game assets

Comment: @Memor-X I feel that might be part of the answer to OP's question.

Comment: So RobotMaster122, to clarify, are you asking what the name is of this specific mod (indicated by screenshot) or are you asking how to create these emancipation grids? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I am asking is there is a name to this mod and/or where I can find it. I already kniw what it does, as the level gave me a hint at each one did.

Answer (score 1):

To create maps that use these, you'll need to be using the Portal 2 Authoring Tools rather than the in-game Puzzle Creator.

Emancipation Grills consist of at least two objects.  One controls what it looks like (`prop_dynamic`) and the other controls what it does (`trigger_portal_cleanser`).  The latter can be configured as to whether allow Physics Objects (like cubes or turrets) or not.

To block objects and allow portals likely requires tweaking different settings so that it acts like a window rather than an emancipation grill.

Source: [Valve Developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Emancipation_Grid)